# Oracle 10g error: "ORA-00028: your session has been killed"

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I have barely no experience with Oracle, so please bear with my noobish question.

I have access to a remote `Oracle 10g` database.

Once I connect via ssh to the machine, I do as follows:

```
sqlplus foo@bar
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Sun Mar 13 12:23:28 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00028: your session has been killed

SQL> SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;
SELECT * FROM MY TABLE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01012: not logged on
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 723 Serial number: 46399


SQL>
```

Basically, I'm getting this every time I try to run a query.

Does any body know why this is happening? How can I run my queries?

Comment: If it happens every time, I think you should contact the site administrator.

Answer (score -1):

I would assume that your SID is not yet set.

Do you have more than one database in the server ? More than one version of DB?

If so set your Oracle_home and Oracle_SID= `<yourDB>`

then try

If that won't work check if you have run short of memory.

Comment: I don't mind the down vote if you could explain why :)

Comment: He wouldn't get those messages to say he's connected. Namely he'd get: ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist. For @Xar perhaps there's a trigger, or he's timing out, I don't know. looking in v$session might help.

Comment: Ow sorry. I tried to ask this on oracle community and what one of them told me is that the problem is limit of parameter processes hit. 
There's no much you can do, except drop some session so that you can connect as sysdba and increase processes. others agreed tho.